# Mavericks QuickTime player not recording computer audio

Tags: audio, macos, quicktime

I was recording the screen on my computer that I had updated to Mavericks, and when I replayed the video, there was no audio except the audio captured by my mic.
The old Qucktime worked fine, but now it's not.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I get system sound along with QuickTime Player screen recording?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/45689/can-i-get-system-sound-along-with-quicktime-player-screen-recording)

Answer (score 4):

I was able to do this by going to Utilities>Audio Midi Setup

Click the + sign to add a new device, choose Create Aggregate Device and click both the Built-In Microphone and Built-In Output checkboxes. Then right click the Aggregate device you just created and choose. Use this for Sound Input. Now this device will appear as in input choice in QuickTime Player X.

Now open QuickTime Player X, choose New Screen Recording and click the drop down arrow. You will now see Aggregate Device as a Mic choice.

Comment: I know it has been a while since you have asked this question, but is there a way to not record the outside sounds? I just want to record whatever sound is coming from my MacBook. Thanks!

Comment: @penatheboss These days you will want to use Soundflower as a virtual Audio Device.  Once your Mac is outputting to Soundflower, you just set Soundflower as the input source for Quicktime. https://github.com/mattingalls/Soundflower/releases/

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you selected an input source(i.e. your internal microphone):

[image: Mavericks Quicktime]

**EDIT:** I tested it with Mac Os X 10.7.4. Like I thought, recording system audio was never implemented(assuming they did not added it in 10.8 just to remove it again with 10.9)

[image: Lion Quicktime]

Comment: I did -_- Im looking for the audio generated on the computer (i.e from a video game). Normally its recorded, but now that I have Maveriks, its not working, along with countless other problems

Comment: afaik this was never possible. If you want to record audio internally please take a look at [soundflower](https://code.google.com/p/soundflower/)